# Android native browser 2.3.7: Youtube iframe API "onReady" event not fired

Tags: javascript, android, backbone.js, youtube-api, android-2.3-gingerbread

I am testing my backbone app on Win/mac chrome & firefox, iPad, iPhone, Android 4.3, Android 4.1.2, and Android 2.3.7. The Youtube iFrame API is working as expected on all platforms except Android 2.3.7 using the native browser. I've tracked it down to the object returned by YT.Player() never firing its onReady event, or any other event for that matter.

onYoutubeIframeAPIReady gets called in all tests, and the player is being instantiated, but something is preventing the "onReady" event from firing.

I've seen some other posts referencing a similar problem in other browsers, but the general response is just that this is an "old bug" and should already be resolved; however, I've tried just a bare bones implementation of the YT.Player on a plain HTML page, and it works in the 2.3.7 native browser, so it does not appear to be a Youtube, browser, or server issue. Not sure what could be happening here as the code is the same across all browsers and is working on everything else. Any help would be appreciated!

Code:

```
_injectScript: function(){
  var tag = document.createElement('script');
  tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
  var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
  firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);
},


render: function(runTimeSettings) {
  var t=this;
  Player.prototype.render.call(this, runTimeSettings);
  window.onYouTubeIframeAPIReady = function() {
    var player = new YT.Player('PlayerReal', {
      events: {
        'onStateChange': function(e) {
          t.dispatchEvent(e);
        },
        'onReady': function(e) {
          t.player = player;
          t.domReady.resolve();
        },
        'onError':function(e) {
          // nothing yet...
        }
      }
    });
  };

  this._injectScript();
  return this.el;
}
```